# Splitting string into two strings with regex

Tags: java, regex, string, split

This question was asked several times before but I couldn't find an answer to my question:
I need to split a string into two strings. First part is date and the second string is text. This is what i got so far:

```
String test = "24.12.17 18:17 TestString";
String[] testSplit = test.split("\\d{2}.\\d{2}.\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}");
System.out.println(testSplit[0]);           // "24.12.17 18:17" <-- Does not work
System.out.println(testSplit[1].trim());    // "TestString" <-- works
```

I can extract "TestString" but i miss the date. Is there any better (or even simpler) way? Help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Is your string always a date with this format followed by an arbitrary text?

Comment: There is an easy way if you don't bother relying on the fact that the date & time has a constant length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to match **only the separator**. By matching the date, you *consume* it (it's thrown away).

Use a *look behind*, which asserts but does not consume:

```
test.split("(?<=^.{14}) ");
```

This regex means "split on a space that is preceded by 14 characters after the start of input".

---

Your test code now works:

```
String test = "24.12.17 18:17 TestString";
String[] testSplit = test.split("(?<=^.{14}) ");
System.out.println(testSplit[0]);           // "24.12.17 18:17" <-- works
System.out.println(testSplit[1].trim());    // "TestString" <-- works
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This exactly answers the question and works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

## Skip regex; Use *three* strings

You are working too hard. No need to include the date and the time together as one. Regex is tricky, and life is short.

Just use the plain [`String::split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) for *three* pieces, and re-assemble the date-time.

```
String[] pieces = "24.12.17 18:17 TestString".split( " " ) ;  // Split into 3 strings.
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( pieces[0] , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.uu" ) ) ;  // Parse the first string as a date value (`LocalDate`).
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( pieces[1] , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "HH:mm" ) ) ;  // Parse the second string as a time-of-day value (`LocalTime`).
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( ld , lt ) ;  // Reassemble the date with the time (`LocalDateTime`).
String description = pieces[2] ;  // Use the last remaining string.
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/5GHm9Z).

> ldt.toString(): 2017-12-24T18:17
>
> description: TestString

Tip: If you have any control over that input, switch to using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for date-time values in text. The [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes use the standard formats by default when generating/parsing strings.

Answer (score 2):

If your string is always in this format (and is formatted well), you do not even need to use a regex. Just split at the second  space using `.substring` and `.indexOf`:

```
String test = "24.12.17 18:17 TestString";
int idx = test.indexOf(" ", test.indexOf(" ") + 1);
System.out.println(test.substring(0, idx));
System.out.println(test.substring(idx).trim());
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/wFRf97).

If you want to make sure your string starts with a datetime value, you may use a **matching** approach to match the string with a pattern containing 2 capturing groups: one will capture the date and the other will capture the rest of the string:

```
String test = "24.12.17 18:17 TestString";
String pat = "^(\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2})\\s(.*)";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pat, Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(test);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2).trim());
}
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/MRuFRC).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2})` - Group 1: a datetime pattern (`xx.xx.xx xx:xx`-like pattern)
- `\\s` - a whitespace (if it is optional, add `*` after it)
- `(.*)` -  Group 2 capturing any 0+ chars up to the end of string (`.` will match line breaks, too, because of the `Pattern.DOTALL` flag).

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, which asks *"I need to split a string into two strings"*

Comment: @Bohemian It **does** answer that question. It **does** split a string that starts with a specific pattern into **two** parts. If you can prove the opposite I will remove the answer.

Comment: The "proof" is the absence of `split` anywhere in your code and there is no `String[]` result. You could *create* a `String[]` somewhere in your code and assign values to its elements, but at that point you might as well code `String[] testResult = new String[2]; testResult[0] = test.substring(0, 14); testResult[1] = test.substring(15);` which is much less code than your answer, and simpler, but still doesn't *split* the string. See my answer for a simple, elegant solution that actually splits the input as requested.

Comment: @Bohemian: There is no requirement in the question to use `split()`. [Split](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/split) means getting parts of a whole, and my code does it. There are several points that prove my solution is better than yours: 1) my solution makes sure we actually have a datetime at the start of the string, 2) if there is no whitespace between the datetime and the rest of the string, my solution will work, yours requires a space, 3) my solution will work even if there is any whitespace, not just a regular space between the datetime and the rest of the string.